# Extending image tag over an existing tag by overlapping

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to extend the image to the top, passed the previous HTML tag. This is what I have so far:

```
 .toggle-modal {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 10px;
  left: 80px;
}
#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
}
<div className='card'>
  <FaRegStar size={20} className='toggle-modal' onClick={openModal}/>
  <Modal toggle={modalState} action={openModal} />
  <div onClick={refreshOverview}>
    {product.image ? (<img src={product.image[0].url} alt={product.name} id='image'/>) : 
    'image not available'
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

[rendered top image card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2u1n.png)